# Kotlin's copy in data class does shallow copy?

Tags: kotlin

So I have the following data class:

```
data class Client(val name: String, val pastAddresses: ArrayList<String>)
```

From the following code:

```
val aClient = Client("Alice", arrayListOf("foo", "bar"))
println(aClient)
val cClient = aClient.copy()
cClient.pastAddresses.add("Blah")
cClient.pastAddresses.remove("foo")
println(aClient)
```

I see:

```
Client(name=Alice, pastAddresses=[foo, bar])
Client(name=Alice, pastAddresses=[bar, Blah])
```

Which means that the copy in Kotlin's data class is a shallow copy.
Is there a way to do a deep copy?

Comment: Use List<String> instead of ArrayList<String>, and the need for a deep copy vanishes, since a List is immutable. If you really want it mutable, it should be typed as MutableList<String>. Program to interfaces, not implementations.

Comment: Generated copy method does create a shallow copy, you're gonna need to write your own deep copying one.

Comment: @JBNizet: Using `listOf` does not compile

Comment: It doesn't compile because your property is of type ArrayList<String>. It should be List<String>, as I said in my comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are right. The default `copy()` method creates a shallow copy.

Look at the [Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html):

> It's often the case that we need to copy an object altering some of
>   its properties, but keeping the rest unchanged. This is what copy()
>   function is generated for.

You can override it so that it does what you need. But I'd suggest you to create a new method that creates a *deep* copy, let name it `deepCopy()`. Why is it better? Because if your application grows, there still can be cases when you need a shallow copy. That's why having 2 different methods can help to clearly distinguish it.